# Кнопка возврата в папках

Tags: javascript

Имеется `json` в котором хранится информация о кнопках и папках. В папках могут быть, как кнопки так и другие папки. При нажатии на кнопку отправляется сообщение. Соответственно при нажатии на папку открывается папка. Папок в папке может быть бесконечное количество. Также при открытии папки появляется кнопка назад. При нажатии которой должен происходить возврат к предыдущей папке или же если папка была последней то возвращаться в исходное положение.

Собственно вопрос как реализовать кнопку назад? У меня получилось сделать только возврат в предыдущий каталог.

```js
const TextLabel = document.querySelector('.texLabel');
const keysList = document.querySelector('#keysList');
const backBtn = document.querySelector('#back');

// Отправка сообщения
keysList.addEventListener('click', sendMessage);

// Открытие папки
keysList.addEventListener('click', openFolder);

// Кнопка назад
backBtn.addEventListener('click', backToFolder);

let DATA = [{"color":"blue","folder":[{"color":"blue","folder":[{"color":"blue","folder":[{"color":"white","id":"b2ed07dc-8ccc-4503-a712-1e8353fd0f7a","key":"Кнопка внтури папок","value":"Текст кнопки внутри папок"}],"id":"eb70f309-abac-4bdf-8cc7-aeb358230bd7","key":"Папка вниутри папки внутри папки"}],"id":"e4143892-abd3-49c0-a400-426c25717157","key":"Папка внутри папки"}],"id":"5881af01-87c9-4fe4-8c45-526f6fa94d00","key":"Папка"},{"color":"white","id":"1bf19d59-754a-4a28-9cff-e6e4e13241f0","key":"Кнопка","value":"Текст кнопки"}]

let CURR_KEYS_SPACE = DATA;
let PREV_FOLDER;

updateKeys();
checkEmptyList();

// Функции

// Открытие папки
function openFolder(event) {
    if (event.target.dataset.action === 'openfolder') {
        PREV_FOLDER = CURR_KEYS_SPACE;
        const parentNode = event.target.closest('.taskWrapper');
        const id = parentNode.id;
        const item = CURR_KEYS_SPACE.find((item) => item.id === id)
        CURR_KEYS_SPACE  = item.folder;
        backBtn.classList.remove("none");
        updateKeys();
    }
}

// Кнопка назад в папке
function backToFolder(event){
    CURR_KEYS_SPACE = PREV_FOLDER;
    updateKeys();
}
// Отправка сообщения
function sendMessage(event) {
    if (event.target.dataset.action === 'send') {
        const parentNode = event.target.closest('.taskWrapper');
        const id = parentNode.id;
        const item = CURR_KEYS_SPACE.find((item) => item.id === id)
        TextLabel.innerHTML = item.value;
    }
}

// Проверка на наличие сохраненных кнопок
function checkEmptyList() {
    
    if (DATA.length === 0) {

        const checkEmptyListHTML = '<div id="emptyList">Добавьте кнопку</div>';

        keysList.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', checkEmptyListHTML);
    }
    if (DATA.length > 0) {
        const emptyListEl = document.querySelector('#emptyList');
        emptyListEl ? emptyListEl.remove() : null;
    }

}


function updateKeys(){
    if (CURR_KEYS_SPACE != "") {
        keysList.innerHTML = "";
        CURR_KEYS_SPACE.forEach((item) => renderKeys(item));
    }
}


// Отрисовка кнопок и папок

function renderKeys(item) {
    if (!item.folder) {

        const taskHTML = `<div id="${item.id}" class="taskWrapper">
                        
        <div class="taskText" data-action="send">${item.key}</div>
                         </div>`;
                         keysList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', taskHTML);
    }
    else {

        const taskHTML = `<div id="${item.id}" class="taskWrapper folder">
                        
        <div class="taskText" data-action="openfolder">${item.key}</div>
                         </div>`;
                         keysList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', taskHTML);


    }
}
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
    background-color: #0e0b0b;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.none {
    display: none !important;
}

.card {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    min-height: 80px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 15pt;
}

.cardName {
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.cardOpen{
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 15pt;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

.folder {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 20px 0, 25px 5px, 100% 5px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    background-color: #555555 !important;
}

.btn {
    height: 30px;
    width: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0e0b0b;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin:  20px auto;
    display: block;
    font-size:  12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover  {
    background-color: #141212;
    color: #b8b5b5;
}

.keysList {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.taskWrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    min-width: 60px;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.texLabel {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    outline: 0px;
    min-height: 36px;
    width: 80%;
    resize: none;
    padding: 9px 106px 10px 13px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0px;
    transition: border-bottom-color 0.3s linear 0s;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.taskText {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.back {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 7px solid transparent;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
    <title>Кнопки</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cardOpen">
    <div class="texLabel" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true"></div>
    <div id="back" class="back none">←</div>
    <div id="keysList" class="keysList"></div>
</div>
<script src="../js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Когда вы используете `PREV_FOLDER`, вы возвращаетесь на 1 каталог назад, как вы и написали. Все, что нужно сделать чтобы вернуться на несколько папок, это иметь массив `history` (ну или `PREV_FOLDERS` если писать в вашем стиле) например. Который будет на подобии стека. То есть при входе в папку в этот массив нужно добавлять папку, а при нажатии на кнопку назад нужно удалять последнюю добавленную папку. А `CURR_KEYS_SPACE` это просто будет последняя в этом массиве папка, что удобно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я писал в комментарии. Чтобы возвращаться назад на сколько угодно папок, нужно хранить полный путь, который был пройден. Для этого идеально подходит стек. В случае `js` это будет массив.

1. Изначально в стеке будет лежать начальная папка `DATA`.
2. При открытии другой папки, в стек будет добавляться объект `folder` из папки по которой кликнули в текущей папке.
3. Текущая папка (если брать аналог из вашего кода, то `CURR_KEYS_SPACE`) это последний элемент в стеке (верхушка стека).
4. При клике "Назад" из стека последний элемент будет убираться, тем самым текущей папкой станет та, из который мы пришли.

Вот пример кода с комментариями:

```js
const TextLabel = document.querySelector('.texLabel');
const keysList = document.querySelector('#keysList');
const backBtn = document.querySelector('#back');

// Отправка сообщения
keysList.addEventListener('click', sendMessage);
// Открытие папки
keysList.addEventListener('click', openFolder);
// Кнопка назад
backBtn.addEventListener('click', backToFolder);

let DATA = [{"color":"blue","folder":[{"color":"blue","folder":[{"color":"blue","folder":[{"color":"white","id":"b2ed07dc-8ccc-4503-a712-1e8353fd0f7a","key":"Кнопка внтури папок","value":"Текст кнопки внутри папок"}],"id":"eb70f309-abac-4bdf-8cc7-aeb358230bd7","key":"Папка вниутри папки внутри папки"}],"id":"e4143892-abd3-49c0-a400-426c25717157","key":"Папка внутри папки"}],"id":"5881af01-87c9-4fe4-8c45-526f6fa94d00","key":"Папка"},{"color":"white","id":"1bf19d59-754a-4a28-9cff-e6e4e13241f0","key":"Кнопка","value":"Текст кнопки"}];

// Сам стек, в котором изначально главная папка находится
const history = [DATA];

updateKeys();
checkEmptyList();

// Функции

// Открытие папки
function openFolder(event) {
    if (event.target.dataset.action === 'openfolder') {
        const parentNode = event.target.closest('.taskWrapper');
        const id = parentNode.id;
        // Тут как и было описано в ответе, берем просто последний элемент
        const item = history[history.length - 1].find((item) => item.id === id)
        // Закидываем папку по которой кликнули в историю
        history.push(item.folder);
        backBtn.classList.remove("none");
        updateKeys();
    }
}

// Кнопка назад в папке
function backToFolder(event) {
    // Убираем последний элемент из стека. Тем самым возвращаемся назад
    history.pop();
    updateKeys();
}

// Отправка сообщения
function sendMessage(event) {
    if (event.target.dataset.action === 'send') {
        const parentNode = event.target.closest('.taskWrapper');
        const id = parentNode.id;
        // Тут так же просто берем последний элемент в стеке
        const item = history[history.length - 1].find((item) => item.id === id)
        TextLabel.innerHTML = item.value;
    }
}

// Проверка на наличие сохраненных кнопок
function checkEmptyList() {
    if (DATA.length === 0) {
        const checkEmptyListHTML = '<div id="emptyList">Добавьте кнопку</div>';
        keysList.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', checkEmptyListHTML);
    }
    if (DATA.length > 0) {
        const emptyListEl = document.querySelector('#emptyList');
        emptyListEl ? emptyListEl.remove() : null;
    }

}

function updateKeys() {
    keysList.innerHTML = "";
    // Берем так же текущую папку (последний элемент в стеке)
    history[history.length - 1].forEach((item) => renderKeys(item));
}

// Отрисовка кнопок и папок
function renderKeys(item) {
    if (!item.folder) {
        const taskHTML = `<div id="${item.id}" class="taskWrapper">
        <div class="taskText" data-action="send">${item.key}</div>
                         </div>`;
        keysList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', taskHTML);
    }
    else {
        const taskHTML = `<div id="${item.id}" class="taskWrapper folder">            
        <div class="taskText" data-action="openfolder">${item.key}</div>
                         </div>`;
        keysList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', taskHTML);
    }
}
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
    background-color: #0e0b0b;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.none {
    display: none !important;
}

.card {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    min-height: 80px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 15pt;
}

.cardName {
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.cardOpen{
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 15pt;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

.folder {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 20px 0, 25px 5px, 100% 5px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    background-color: #555555 !important;
}

.btn {
    height: 30px;
    width: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0e0b0b;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin:  20px auto;
    display: block;
    font-size:  12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover  {
    background-color: #141212;
    color: #b8b5b5;
}

.keysList {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.taskWrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    min-width: 60px;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.texLabel {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    outline: 0px;
    min-height: 36px;
    width: 80%;
    resize: none;
    padding: 9px 106px 10px 13px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0px;
    transition: border-bottom-color 0.3s linear 0s;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.taskText {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.back {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 7px solid transparent;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
    <title>Кнопки</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="cardOpen">
      <div class="texLabel" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true"></div>
      <div id="back" class="back none">←</div>
      <div id="keysList" class="keysList"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

P.s. пытался по минимуму изменить ваш код, чтобы было проще понять в чем заключается идея. Возможно мой код не впишется в какие-то ваши идеи (я просто не особо вдавался в подробности той же функции `checkEmptyList`), но думаю вы сможете под свои нужны его переделать. Я просто показал пример реализации.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за пример. Буду разбираться. Функция checkEmptyList() нужна мне для того что в будщем собираюсь сделать удаление и добавление кнопок и папок.